# Can I use a visual editor on Template Manager?

Tags: rte, editor

I have an ExpressionEngine website built for a client, and the entire content is built inside a template.

I need to allow the client to make modifications, but I don't want the source to be visible by default.

All plugins only work with channel content, not with the Template Manager.

**EDIT #1:** Found this, but it's for EE 1.x, and it needs to be updated for 2.x - http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/56223/

*The ideal solution would be injecting a RTE editor to convert the Template Manager textarea into a visual editor.*

Comment: Can you elaborate, explain a bit what you mean by: "entire content is in a template". Is it a static webpage without any EE tags?

Comment: It is a static webpage, yes, only HTML and Javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd use EE in this way. The whole point is to move content out of templates, so it's easier for clients to edit. If they're just editing raw HTML, a static .html file would be easier to deal with than the overhead of a CMS.

Comment: Sounds like the EE install is set up very poorly and not being used as it should. You can move the content into entries and the client can easily edit.

Comment: I understand, but there are no resources to set up entries and channels. I know it would be much easier, but I only need to make the Template Manager easier to work with.

Comment: When you say there are "no resources" to set up channels and entries" it's like a 10 minute job... 20 minutes max. From your earlier comment it just sounds like you don't know EE and so feel it would be more difficult than it actually is.

Comment: When I say resources, I say developers and money. I just inherited the CMS and I need to make EXACTLY that change ASAP. No alternatives, no options, no nothing. It's a very rigid system, you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's static content within a template and you don't want to give the client access to the template then you have a couple of options;

1. Use a global variable or snippet, the client can edit this without touching the full template... though you won't have WYSIWYG editing.
2. Create a channel entry and replace the content in the template with the tags for to output that entry. This would seem the "best" way to me as it will give you the most flexibility and is still pretty quick to set up in EE. It probably won't take more than 20 minutes and will give you exactly what you need.

> "The ideal solution would be injecting a RTE editor to convert the
>   Template Manager textarea into a visual editor."

This "solution" makes no sense within the context you are working. In all honesty it would take longer and be more problematic than *any* of the other options presented in this thread. If you approach the problem from a more appropriate angle, you'll find it much easier. Regardless of your personal like or dislike of a given system it's in your interests to work with the tool, not against it.

Comment: I've done some research and I'd go with your second suggestion. Although I have lots of code and Javascript inside that template, I might pull it off. My proposed "solution" also appears in my edited link (see original post), so someone created that for EE 1.x. I'll just accept your answer, as number 2 seems the most appropriate.

Comment: EE1 and EE2 are very different beasts, written on different platforms. The reason there is no add-on to inject a WYSIWYG control into the template editor is that it's a really bad idea. It's just not the place to do content editing. Think of it as giving your client access to your Wordpress theme files to make content edits. It's possible but would most likely end in tears. If they need a visual editor then it's better they didn't make changes to templates. EE provides a number of alternatives of which a few have been outlined here.

Comment: if original poster insists on cramming in a WYSIWYG into the system then i'ld go with snippets. at least then you'ld be able to use a strip ee-tags plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) to manage the template content; that would abstract the maintenance to an interface and leave the template out of the process entirely.

Your question is not very clear though; how is the content getting into the template? Presumably you have channels; can your client not edit the channel entries to update the site?

Or do you want them to edit from the front-end (and so never actually log in to the CP?) In which case you'd probably need to use [channel_form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/) tags and build a front-end editing template separately.

Comment: Low Variables looks OK, but it's hard to implement. There are no channels, just templates, that's why I need to be able to edit them in a user-friendly manner.

Comment: Low Variables is not hard to implement. So easy! It's the user-friendly manner you are asking for.

Comment: See the original question, I'm not interested in alternatives. I've updated it with what I'd like to accomplish. Thank you.